# How to get phone number for each SMS on the device?

Tags: android, sms

I'm getting all phone's SMS with this URI - `Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI`

`TextBasedSmsColumns` contains all columns for a projection.

Cursor is built like this:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] { BaseColumns._ID, TextBasedSmsColumns.ADDRESS },
                        null, null, null);
```

There is a `TextBasedSmsColumns.ADDRESS` column that contains a phone number OR a contact name. So how can I *always* get the phone number for the SMS? Should I use another approach to get all SMS?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got.

```
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
if (cur != null) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String body = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
            //Here you will get all PhoneNumbers
            String phoneNumber = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address"));
        }
        cur.close();
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, if you rename the contact on your phone then "address" will return a name not a phone number. Also you should not use hardcoded strings, for example use Telephony.Sms.Inbox.CONTENT_URI instead of "content://sms/inbox"